# Dynamic content of app-header using Polymer Starter Kit

Tags: javascript, layout, polymer

I am writing an app using the Polymer Starter Kit, which uses the app-layout elements.

I would like to have different contents in app-header depending on the page being viewed. For example a list of people will have a menu to enable filtering, etc. The title will change too.

It's important that each *page* decides what goes into app-header.

What's the neatest way to do this?

I can think of different paths: having a `iron-page`-like selector within app-header could work; but... as I said, ideally each page would have an element that would then be "placed" there.

Maybe using global variables too?

Thoughts?

Comment: Like you said, one way is to use `iron-pages` in header where selected of `iron-pages` can be mapped to some property of main content elements so that each page decides which element to use for header. Also, you can lazy load the header elements just like page element.

Comment: Another way is (more applicable if your elements have layout of header) to create your header element such that each page can pass is metadata regarding what element(icon) to show at which place and what data to pass to it. (This can get messy pretty fast)

Comment: I thought of iron-pages in main element, but I can't work out how to make it _actually_ work. I am thinking of having a placeholder tag in app-header, and then when the route changes the main app swaps the first child with a specified element of the right page, but it feels over-engineered...

Comment: Here's a slightly different idea. Move `app-header` inside of your `page-elements`. Each page element can define its own app-header view that way. Something like [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/iD6nxRgdNgMBZxLw1SbF)

Comment: I am battling this as we speak. https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-layout/issues/255